# Selenium: find_element_by_link_text - TypeError: Object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

Tags: django, selenium

I am doing a test development tutorial for Django.  http://www.tdd-django-tutorial.com/tutorial/1/

When I run a test, I get a problem with find_element_by_link_text.  The error shows:

```
find_element_by_link_text - TypeError: Object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

The part of the test that is failing is this one:

```
    polls_links = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Polls')
    self.assertEquals(len(polls_links), 2)
```

If I remove those lines the tests work properly, the Polls model is added on the admin. In the admin site, during Selenium test, there are 2 links with the text 'Polls'.

The problem does not seem to be that it is not recognizing them, the problem seems to be what find_element_by_link_text returns...I don't know

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I did some research and apparently it has to do with Selenium driver for Firefox, but I have not been able to clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is your problem.

```
polls_links = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Polls')
```

You need to add the `.text` method to return the text of the element and not the element itself.

```
polls_links = self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Polls').text
```

Answer (score 9):

It's

```
polls_links = self.browser.find_elements_by_link_text('Polls')
```

i.e. `elements` (with an `s`) and not `element`

Comment: This is the correct answer, find_element_by_link_text expects a set of one, whereas, find_elements_by_link_text expects a set of one or more